# URL Rewriting in Joomla

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

HI

i want to rewrite my home menu

http://example.com/main/ to http://example.com/main/index.php only . How can i do this using .htaccess

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a [`DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) directive to your `.htaccess` file, e.g.:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

though I think this should work out of the box, so there might be something else wrong. Are you sure that `mod_dir` is loaded properly? (Look at the output of `phpinfo()` and search for `mod_dir`, it should be there.)